# Looking for a DataGrid Control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have been trying to find both built-in datagrid control and third party datagrid control for windows phone 7 but with no luck. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: I don't recommend using DataGrid control in WP7. I cannot imagine how difficult it would be to manipulate data in it on phone. Would you let us know why you want it?

Comment: well. it does not have to be datagrid. Listview control will do.. but no such a control in WP7. Simple, all I need to display data in table-format fashion on WP7.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can do this with a simple listbox or (if you want images in your grid) the [deferred load Listbox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/10/04/there-s-no-substitute-for-customer-feedback-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-now-a-bit-easier-with-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx). Here's some simple XAML to show you how:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <HyperLinkButton Content="{Binding Path=Description}" NavigateUri="{Binding Path=UriForEditingResource}"
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LongDescription}" Grid.Column="1" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the above example I assume that you setting the myListBox control's ItemSource to a collection of objects whose class contains 3 properties (Description, LongDescription, and UriForEditingResource). There are 2 columns in my example and these columns will be of equal size and they should take over all the available space.

Use Blend to edit these (it will be much easier for you). BTW, I inlined my datatemplate. Blend will typically create a resource for the data template (which means you can re-use datatemplates.

I hope that helps you out some (BTW, the ListBox is not the only control you can do this type of thing with, so study the available controls).

Jay